# ReferenceError: Can't find variable __fbBatchedBridge

Tags: android, react-native

EDIT: It's worth noting I'm developing on Android right now

I am getting the `__fbBatchedBridge` error on my ReactNative app. The issue is NOT a failure to connect to the packager (evidence thereof is below). The issue started when I installed a bunch of packages for testing, but even when I reverted, deleted `node_modules`, and did `npm install` it persists.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "log": "adb logcat *:S ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "events": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native": "^0.18.0",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^1.0.2",
    "react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "^0.3.5",
    "react-native-webrtc": "^0.2.7",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.0",
    "redux": "^3.3.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^1.4.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "redux-devtools": "^3.1.1"
  }
}
```

**npm start results**

```
[7:19:50 PM] <START> Building Dependency Graph
[7:19:50 PM] <START> Crawling File System
[7:19:50 PM] <START> Loading bundles layout
[7:19:50 PM] <END>   Loading bundles layout (0ms)

React packager ready.

[7:19:53 PM] <START> request:/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true
[7:19:53 PM] <START> find dependencies
[7:19:56 PM] <END>   Crawling File System (5686ms)
[7:19:56 PM] <START> Building in-memory fs for JavaScript
[7:19:56 PM] <END>   Building in-memory fs for JavaScript (346ms)
[7:19:56 PM] <START> Building in-memory fs for Assets
[7:19:56 PM] <END>   Building in-memory fs for Assets (322ms)
[7:19:56 PM] <START> Building Haste Map
[7:19:56 PM] <START> Building (deprecated) Asset Map
[7:19:57 PM] <END>   Building (deprecated) Asset Map (87ms)
[7:19:57 PM] <END>   Building Haste Map (452ms)
[7:19:57 PM] <END>   Building Dependency Graph (6811ms)
[7:19:57 PM] <END>   find dependencies (4018ms)
[7:19:57 PM] <START> transform
transforming [========================================] 100% 549/549
[7:20:00 PM] <END>   transform (3417ms)
[7:20:00 PM] <END>   request:/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true (7463ms)
```

As you can see, the packager *is* packaging and sending the bundle to Genymotion, which is then raising the error.

Comment: Does the react native versions match between ios and javascript?

Comment: I'm only developing for Android right now, but yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is fixed in newer version of React Native. I would advice you to please upgrade your version to `0.22`.

However, If you're looking for temporary fix than in `node_modules/react-native/packager/packager.sh`

replace

```
if [[ "$PLATFORM_NAME" = "iphonesimulator" ]]; then
  echo "Skipping bundling for Simulator platform"
  exit 0;
fi
```

with

```
#    if [[ "$PLATFORM_NAME" = "iphonesimulator" ]]; then        
#      echo "Skipping bundling for Simulator platform"      
#      exit 0;      
#    fi
```

Comment: Upgrading React Native did it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

At AppDelegate.m file, we will using :

```
jsCodeLocation = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true"];
```

instead of :

```
jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
```

It work for me.

Answer (score 0):

From terminal:

`adb shell input keyevent 82`

Genymotion opens dev menu, go to **Dev Settings**

Then: `adb shell input text <your IPv4 adress>:8081`

And finally:

`adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`